# Connect MySQL workbench to a putty manager

Tags: mysql-workbench, putty

I'm a newbie in using Putty connection manager (PCM). My problem in short is to use JDBC connection to connect to a MySQL database running in PCM. I'm accessing this remote database from a local Putty Connection Manager Version 0.7.1 Beta.

I want to setup a SSH login based connection in Workbench. I want to know the pre-requisites to be downloaded and the step to successfully test the connection from workbench.

PS-
I've recently configured my PCM with username as lost_root and some ppk file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Putty to connect MySQL Workbench to a remote server via SSH. Everything needed is already in the application. Use the wizard for new connections and select "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" from the type drop down (Connection Method). Follow the steps and fill in your details as requested.